# python decimal module without exp

Tags: python, scientific-notation

So I use Decimal module to handle really small numbers, cuz I don't want them to be written as `3E-7` or something like this. It works for numbers like `0.000003` but if I add another zero, so this would be `0.0000003`, the results are different:

```
>>> a = 0.0000003
>>> b = 0.000003
>>> Decimal(a)
Decimal('2.999999999999999864244335477658776056841816171072423458099365234375E-7')
>>> Decimal(b)
Decimal('0.000003000000000000000076002572291233860823922441340982913970947265625')
```

So I don't want `a` to be written as `somethingE-something`, because I need to write those numbers in a `.docx` file, which my lecturer will be marking. How can I make it convert really small numbers withour writing them in scientific notation?

Comment: "So I use Decimal module to handle really small numbers, cuz I don't want them to be written as 3E-7 or something like this" - `Decimal` has absolutely nothing to do with that. If you want to change your output formatting, use one of Python's tools for [formatted output](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings).

Comment: But I don't want to print them, I want to store them

Comment: Format converts to a string value: write that directly to the file, or save it in a string variable for later use.

Comment: Okay, but. If I got `a = 0.0000003`, then I go `f = format(a, ".10f")` I've got a string, but then I want to round it, and I cannot round a string

Comment: @Frynio then use regular numbers and right before you "store it" (write to a file?) or print it, thats when you format it.

Comment: I did this: `value = format(round(float(number), some_value), ".10f")`, what do you think?